# How do I hard code the raw-character "83" in RStudio?

Tags: r, codepages

In R, there is something called raw-vector/raw-characters. The one from the "rawToChar" and "charToRaw" functions etc. If you put a raw-vector into the console, it gets printed. One such raw element might be printed as "83". Now I want to check whether for a given raw-character, it is equal to the raw-character that is printed as "83". So I want to put that raw-character hard-coded into my code to compare against. How do I do it?
The only way I found is using charToRaw("ƒ"). However this only works in the console. Putting ƒ into the source-code of an RStudio file is difficult. Just try:

```
print("ƒ")
```

That will give as output:
[1] "Æ’"
If the print-statement is in a compiled RStudio file (it only works as expected in the console).

Comment: Do you know what int to use? Both intToUtf8(83) and intToUtf8(8*16+3) give results different from charToRaw("ƒ")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `83` is a raw value, i.e., a hexadecimal number.

You can use this:

```
intToUtf8(8 * 16 + 3) == "ƒ"
#[1] TRUE
```

or this

```
x <- rawToChar(as.raw(8*16+3))
Encoding(x) <- "latin1"
x == "ƒ"
#[1] TRUE
```

It's dangerous and not necessary to hard-code a UTF-8 character in source code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I initially was a bit confused because intToUtf8(8 * 16 + 3) prints as \u0083, however it is indeed the same raw value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following 2 and it works for me

from console

```
> print("ƒ")
[1] "ƒ"
```

within a function

```
> for (i in 1:3) {
+   print("ƒ")
+ }
[1] "ƒ"
[1] "ƒ"
[1] "ƒ"
```

Can you open File -> Reopen with Encoding -> Select UTF-8 and try once

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I tried changing the encoding to UTF-8, but it had no effect.

Comment: To add, the problem occurs only when the character is in a compiled file and then the function in that file is called in the commandline. Copy-pasting that for-loop into the console works for me